# File carving/recovering software 14.04.01

Tags: external-hdd, scanning

The story starts: Running ubuntu 13.10 -> copy files external -> update 14.04 -> copy files external -> update 14.10 -> Copy files external -> back to 14.04.1 -> Having no files in the external drive. I copied about 30 Gb pictures and documents. (I followed the work every single time)
The external hdd works fine, without any extra sounds. I can find the folder where the files was supposed to be. And the windows recovery folder.

Does anyone know a really good file carving/recovering software?

I'm having a hard time with my: WD my passport ultra external hard drive.

My wife has a plenty of important documents I need to get recovered.

I got the images from the drive using Testdisk/Photorec with no problem at all. But the document's came up as .db files at most.

I tried the Magicrescue software too and found a lot of files but there were .OLE files and corrupted and not readable documents with 21000 pages.

I do not mind to pay a reasonable amount. It only needs to work on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04.01) because it is the only operating system we have.

And is it true that only scanning a hard drive does affect the files?

The hard drive in the laptop is a SSD 128Gb and no results when I scan it in these programs. After installing Ubuntu, I have been forced to use it to get some things done.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise, if possible, to work from a cloned image of the external drive using dd. This would greatly reduce any chance of further problems in using the drive itself.

You could also try Foremost. I've had some luck in recovering files with this software. It has similar features to Photorec.

Comment: I have a 500Gb external HDD and a 128Gb SSD. 
Is it possible to make a image on a 500Gb to a 128Gb?
Running foremost scan now.
There is not a software that's on market to linux?
Found this but market software not working on linux:http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Data_Recovery

Comment: Um ... no. If you're using dd, it will typically create an ISO of the same size as the drive itself. You'll need another drive of the same size *or greater*.

Comment: That was what I was affraid off. Do I ruin my files only by reading them with foremost, etc. even if the drive is physically okay?
What I mean is if there is any idea to send my drive some place they are still able to fix it?

Comment: If the drive is physically fine and you're confident that it can cope with the time required for a recovery, then just use Foremost and hope for the best.